# How do i run a prolog file

Tags: prolog, dcg

this is my first time programing with prolog so I dont know my way around it, i've written the code but how do I execute it in prolog here the code:

```
id --> letter, digitsLetters.
digitsLetters --> digit, digitsLetters.
digitsLetters --> letter, digitsLetters.
digitsLetters --> [].

positive_digits --> sign, digits.
sign --> "+"; [].
digits --> digit; digit, digits.

letter --> "A"; "B"; "C"; "D"; "E"; "F"; "G"; "H"; "I"; "J"; "K"; "L"; "M".
letter --> "N"; "O"; "P"; "Q"; "R"; "S"; "T"; "U"; "V"; "W"; "X"; "Y"; "Z".
letter --> "a"; "b"; "c"; "d"; "e"; "f"; "g"; "h"; "i"; "j"; "k"; "l"; "m".
letter --> "n"; "o"; "p"; "q"; "r"; "s"; "t"; "u"; "v"; "w"; "x"; "y"; "z".
letter -->  "_".

digit --> "0".
digit --> "1".
digit --> "2".
digit --> "3".
digit --> "4".
digit --> "5".
digit --> "6".
digit --> "7".
digit --> "8".
digit --> "9".
```

Comment: Probably with something like `phrase(id, \`test\`)`. Consider [consulting the DCG documentation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=DCG).

Answer (score 0):

1 .*Make* it from the *Compile* tab and Save it

2 . Open SWI-Prolog > File > Consult > Now open the saved above code file name will 
    like  FileName.Pl

3 . Now Type your method name and it's arguments then > Enter,

Comment: is this referring to a particular graphical interface?

Comment: Yes *SWI-Prolog*

Comment: Are you referring to the windows swi-prolog console application by any chance? In theory swi-prolog is a terminal-based client, so it doesn't have a graphical interface. Or are you referring to one of the gui / IDE solutions here: http://www.swi-prolog.org/IDE.html ?